# Last Success and Last Failure Columns in Jenkins Dashboard is not getting updated properly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have Installed Jenkins in my system as a Local Host, I Created a Job with Multi Configuration Project and then configured a  Batch File which executes Automation Pack which is developed in Selenium C#. After Execution of the Job, in Jenkins Dashboard "Last Success" Column is always shown as NA and Last Failure Column is updated with the time executed.

Every time I execute my Job, irrespective of the Automation Execution whether it is passed or failed, Last Failure Column is updated and Last Success Column is always NA.

Is there any configuration changes needs to be done so that I can see the Last Success Column updated in case of my Automation Passed and Last Failure Column updated in case of my Automation Failed.

I did all my searches but was unable to crack. Any solution to this issue is highly appreciated. Let me know if any further details are required.

Note: Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Is your job passing, like Jenkins ending the process as "SUCCESS", are you returning a state of `exit 0` as end of the batch script to trigger a success state

Comment: Saravanan - I have updated the issue below. Could you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I have given beloww script in Execute Windows Batch Command

@echo off
echo Execute SAFE
E:
Cd E:\SAFE\EIC.Automation\bin\Debug
"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" EIC.Automation.dll --testparam=ProjectName=TestProject
nunit-console /xml:console-test.xml nunit.tests.dll
exit 0

In Console Output I am getting this Log and I think "The batch file cannot be found." has something to do with Build Failure.

Started by upstream project "PortalPhase2Sanity" build number 23
originally caused by:
 Started by user Anand Athtihan
Running as SYSTEM
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestProject\default
[default] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins4454585194746729401.bat
Execute SAFE
NUnit Console Runner 3.10.0 (.NET 2.0)
Copyright (c) 2019 Charlie Poole, Rob Prouse
Monday, May 11, 2020 10:36:17 AM

Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    EIC.Automation.dll

=> EIC.Automation.Startup
Clean up Started
Clean up Completed
Clean up Completed
File Name is E:\SAFE\AutomationProjects\TestProject\Reports\SAFE_EXECUTION_11_05_2020_10_36_19.html

Run Settings
    DisposeRunners: True
    WorkDirectory: E:\SAFE\SAFE\EIC.Automation\bin\Debug
    TestParametersDictionary: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
    TestParameters: ProjectName=TestProject
    ImageRuntimeVersion: 4.0.30319
    ImageTargetFrameworkName: .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2
    ImageRequiresX86: False
    ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver: False
    NumberOfTestWorkers: 4

Test Run Summary
  Overall result: Passed
  Test Count: 1, Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
  Start time: 2020-05-11 14:36:18Z
    End time: 2020-05-11 14:37:16Z
    Duration: 58.359 seconds

Results (nunit3) saved as TestResult.xml
The batch file cannot be found.
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level E:\SAFE\AutomationProjects\TestProject\Reports to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\TestProject\configurations\builds\23\htmlreports\TestProjectReport
Finished: FAILURE

any suggestions to the above issue...